# How to read an array of binary data from a file in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Trying to read a binary file of `Word8`, I have the following program:

```
import qualified Data.Binary as B
type Chars = [B.Word8]

printChars :: Chars -> IO()
printChars cs = mapM_ print cs

main :: IO()
main = do
  chars <- B.decodeFile "chars"
  printChars chars
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
$ ./test
test: too few bytes. Failed reading at byte position 241
```

It seems `decodeFile` expects an infinite list. 
How can I tell it to just read as many elements as possible?

Edit:

Here was the code I was looking for: (This works with any type, not just Word8.)

```
import Prelude hiding ( readFile )
import Data.ByteString.Lazy ( readFile )
import Data.Binary.Get ( isEmpty, runGet )
import qualified Data.Binary as B

type Chars = [B.Word8]

printChars :: Chars -> IO()
printChars cs = mapM_ print cs

-- see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html
-- function getTrades
getChars = do
  e <- isEmpty
  if e then return []
  else do
    c <- B.get
    cs <- getChars
    return (c:cs)

main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- readFile "chars"
  printChars $ runGet getChars input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.Binary` is used to serialize known types in a canonical way (defined by the `Binary` class instance).  In general it isn't intended for unstructured data.

In the case you gave us, you are attempting to deserialize the bytes in a file to an object of type [B.Word8].  If you look in the `Data.Binary` source code, you can see the following

```
instance Binary a => Binary [a] where
    get    = do n <- get :: Get Int
            getMany n
```

which basically means that arrays are stored as follows

```
[length of array, val1, val2, ....]
```

so, when you applied the value to the file, it read the first Int in the file (no doubt, a very large number), then attempted to read that number of values.

If you just want to load the file as bytes, you should use `Data.ByteString.getContents`